# SFML 2.1 set all text

Tags: c++, text, sfml

Is there any way to set all the text I have or some specified text all to the same font, color, etc?
It would be a lot faster and easier to do that, instead of doing this:

```
text1.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
text2.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
text3.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
...
```

I'm using SFML 2.1 in C++98.

Comment: If you have C++11 enabled you can use variadic templates to achieve what you want.

Comment: Strongly advised that you upgrade to C++11 - it's got some VERY nice features!

Comment: What IDE/compiler are you using? It might be as simple as sending your compiler a flag to tell it you want to use C++11 instead.

Comment: I'm using Code Blocks.

Comment: Are you also using GCC as your compiler?

Comment: Compiler: GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: Same setup as me, then. https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html shows what C++11 features are supported by each GCC version. To enable C++11 support in Code::Blocks when using GCC, you have to enable the C++11 compiler flag. Right-click your project and select "build options", then select the option with the flag "-std=c++11" (chances are you want to do this for the project, debug, and release). Once that's done, you should have access to all the C++11 features granted by your GCC version. Simple!

Comment: No trouble! Make sure you take a look at my revised answer below. I'd also advise looking over Appendix B (brief overview of C++11) at http://www.learncpp.com. If I am correct about you being a fledgeling C++ programmer, consider reading through the lessons on the site; I started learning C++ there, and am MUCH better for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Text` instances are this similar, it might make sense to keep them in a `std::vector` or some other container class. If they can be sensibly placed in such a container, you can simply loop through them and change whatever properties you wish:

```
for (std::vector<sf::Text>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it)
{
    it->setColor(sf::Color::Black);
    it->setFont(myfont);
}
```

**Edit given interest in C++11 in comments:**

In C++11 this becomes even simpler as a result of [automatic type deduction](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-2-long-long-auto-decltype-nullptr-and-enum-classes/) and [range-based for loops](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-3-range-based-for-statements-and-static_assert/). The syntax above simplifies to:

```
for (auto& text : myvector)            //don't miss the & or 'text' will be read-only!
{
    text.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
    text.setFont(myfont);
}
```